# Cannot read property 'emailVerified' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am trying to get the current user and want to set the user values to a getter. In the constructor I can see the console it is returning email verified to true but when  I am trying to set it the getter it is showing Cannot read property 'emailVerified' of undefined. Please find my code below.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthService {

  userData: any; // Save logged in user data

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

    /* logged in and setting up null when logged out */
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        console.log(this.userData, this.userData.emailVerified)

      } else {
        this.userData = null;
      }
    })
  }

  // Returns true when user is looged in and email is verified
  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = this.userData;
    return ( user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false ) ? true : false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Returns true when user is logged in and email is verified:

```
  get isLoggedIn(): boolean { 
    const user = this.userData;
    if(user === null || user === undefined) return false
    return user.emailVerified;
  }
```

Comment: I guess the first check should be **typeof user == 'undefined'** to avoid any error

Answer (score 0):

Unlike regular functions, arrow functions do not have their own `this` that's you are unable to access the **emailVerified** key and giving you an error like `Cannot read property 'emailVerified' of undefined`

Please check this code try again :

```
/* logged in and setting up null when logged out */
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe( function(user) {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        console.log(this.userData, this.userData.emailVerified)

      } else {
        this.userData = null;
      }
    })
```

I think this will work